# How can I avoid a '&' symbol in a POST in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm sending HTML trough POST and the '&'s are messing it up, how can I avoid it? Tried replacing & with \&, didn't work.

For more info: I'm trying to use email templates in an in-house project and stuff like &nbsp is screwing up the POST i'm using to send them from javascript to php.

code below:

```
emailcontinut = CKEDITOR.instances['emailContinut'].getData();
var parametri = "Trimite="+trimite + "&codc="+codc + "&emailSubiect="+emailsubiect + "&emailContinut="+emailcontinut + "&adact="+adact + "&sid="+Math.random();


xmlhttp_email_actiune.open("POST",url,true);
xmlhttp_email_actiune.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp_email_actiune.setRequestHeader("Content-length", parametri.length);
xmlhttp_email_actiune.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xmlhttp_email_actiune.send(parametri);
```

when I echo $_POST['emailContinut'] in the target PHP, it stops at the first '&' in an &nbsp

the solution was just

```
emailcontinut =  escape(emailcontinut);
```

in javascript and then using stripslashes() in php to decode it. thanks.

Comment: `&` through `POST` ? Give us an `url` example!!

Comment: In what way is an `&` 'messing it up'? Are you sure it's `post` and not `get`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the escape JS function to encode the URL and send the ajax call using encoded URL eg:

```
var url = "http://127.0.0.1/ajaxResource.php?p1=100&p2=2000&p3=name";
url = escape(url); //Now the user is encoded use this url in ajax
```

JP

Answer (score 3):

You need to URL-encode and/or HTML-encode your content, depending on what you're actually doing.

Comment: I'm just sending some HTML trough POST (with ajax) and echo'ing it on another page and it always breaks at the first &

Comment: @Bogdan: Define "it" and "breaks."  You're doing multiple things which work in different ways.  How does it break?

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace them with `&amp;`

It works for href- and src-attributes in HTML